# Insert data to table column from column of different table

Tags: oracle, insert, procedure

I am using Oracle Database.

I have view called VW_MREQ
It has column as follows :

```
M_Product_ID
AD_Client_ID 
AD_ORG_ID
```

It has records inside.

Then, I have empty table called M_Requisition
It has column as follows :

```
M_Product_ID
AD_Client_ID
AD_ORG_ID
DESCRIPTION
CREATEDBY
```

I am making Procedure and would like to insert Data manually to `M_Requisition`, the foreign key is `M_Product_ID` and I want the `AD_Client_ID` and `AD_ORG_ID` to be the same as in `VM_REQ` as I insert `M_Product_ID` to `M_Requisition` manually.

```
INSERT INTO M_Requisition(M_Product_ID, AD_Client_ID, AD_ORG_ID, DESCRIPTION, CREATEDBY) VALUES(123, ?? , ??,"Insert Data","Me")
```

I plan to use `SELECT INTO` but still confused how I arrange it as I am newbie in Oracle.

Your help will be useful.

Comment: I'm not clear what the problem is. The insert statement ought to be all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the insert-select syntax, and just query the hardcoded values as literals:

```
INSERT INTO M_Requisition
(M_Product_ID, AD_Client_ID, AD_ORG_ID, DESCRIPTION, CREATEDBY)
(SELECT 123, AD_Client_ID, AD_ORG_ID, 'Insert Data', 'Me'
 FROM   VW_MREQ)
```